# Not able to open MainActivity getting nullPointer exception

Tags: android, android-studio, nullpointerexception

MainActivity.java

```
    package com.pKLabs.RgpvDigest;


import android.content.ActivityNotFoundException;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.res.Configuration;
import android.graphics.Paint;
import android.graphics.Typeface;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle;
import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.MenuItem.OnMenuItemClickListener;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.view.animation.AlphaAnimation;
import android.view.animation.Animation;
import android.view.animation.Animation.AnimationListener;
import android.view.animation.AnimationUtils;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.android.gms.ads.AdListener;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.AdRequest;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.InterstitialAd;

import cssyllabus.MainCS;

import static com.pKLabs.RgpvDigest.R.layout.activity_main;

public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity implements
        OnItemClickListener, AnimationListener {
    private DrawerLayout drawerLayout;
    private ListView listView;
    private ActionBarDrawerToggle drawerListner;
    TextView t, t1, t2, t3, t4, t5;
    Animation rotation, anim;
    private MyAdapter myAdapter;
    private static final String AD_UNIT_ID = "ca-app-pub-8935153656417807/4125750777";
    private static final String TAG = "MainActivity";
    private InterstitialAd iAd;
    ImageView iv;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        anim = new AlphaAnimation(0.0f, 1.0f);
        anim.setDuration(60); // You can manage the blinking time with this
                                // parameter
        anim.setStartOffset(30);
        anim.setRepeatMode(Animation.REVERSE);
        anim.setRepeatCount(2);

        iv = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1);

        rotation = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getApplicationContext(),
                R.anim.button_rotate);
        rotation.setRepeatCount(Animation.INFINITE);
        rotation.setAnimationListener(MainActivity.this);

        iv.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                iv.startAnimation(rotation);
                t1.startAnimation(anim);
                t2.startAnimation(anim);
                t3.startAnimation(anim);
                t4.startAnimation(anim);
                t5.startAnimation(anim);
            }
        });

        t = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.rgpvtext);
        t.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                iv.startAnimation(rotation);
                t1.startAnimation(anim);
                t2.startAnimation(anim);
                t3.startAnimation(anim);
                t4.startAnimation(anim);
                t5.startAnimation(anim);

            }
        });

        Typeface tf = Typeface.createFromAsset(getApplicationContext()
                .getAssets(), "segoe.ttf");
        TextView t = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.rgpvtext);
        t.setTypeface(tf);
        t.setTypeface(tf, tf.BOLD);

        iAd = new InterstitialAd(this);
        iAd.setAdUnitId(AD_UNIT_ID);

        iAd.setAdListener(new AdListener() {
            @Override
            public void onAdLoaded() {

            }

            @Override
            public void onAdFailedToLoad(int errorCode) {


            }
        });

        loadInterstitial();

        listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.drawerlist);





        myAdapter = new MyAdapter(this);

        listView.setAdapter(myAdapter);
        listView.setOnItemClickListener(this);
        drawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        drawerListner = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, drawerLayout,
                R.drawable.ic_drawer, R.string.dopen, R.string.dclose);

        drawerLayout.setDrawerListener(drawerListner);
        getSupportActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
        getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);



        t1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.compu);
        t1.setPaintFlags(Paint.UNDERLINE_TEXT_FLAG);
        t1.setTypeface(tf);
        t1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                Intent intent = new Intent(v.getContext(), Semester.class);
                startActivityForResult(intent, 0);
            }
        });

        t2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.calc);
        t2.setPaintFlags(Paint.UNDERLINE_TEXT_FLAG);
        t2.setTypeface(tf);
        t2.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                Intent intent = new Intent(v.getContext(), Calculator.class);
                startActivityForResult(intent, 0);
            }
        });

        t3 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.iv);
        t3.setPaintFlags(Paint.UNDERLINE_TEXT_FLAG);
        t3.setTypeface(tf);
        t3.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                Intent intent = new Intent(v.getContext(),
                        InterviewQuestion.class);
                startActivityForResult(intent, 0);
            }
        });

        t4 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.prog);
        t4.setPaintFlags(Paint.UNDERLINE_TEXT_FLAG);
        t4.setTypeface(tf);
        t4.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                Intent intent = new Intent(v.getContext(), Programs.class);
                startActivityForResult(intent, 0);
            }
        });

        t5 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.abo);
        t5.setPaintFlags(Paint.UNDERLINE_TEXT_FLAG);
        t5.setTypeface(tf);
        t5.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                Intent intent = new Intent(v.getContext(), About.class);
                startActivityForResult(intent, 0);
            }
        });

    }

    private void loadInterstitial() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();

        iAd.loadAd(adRequest);
        System.out.println("Ad loaded success");

    }

    public void showInterstitial() {
        if (iAd.isLoaded()) {
            iAd.show();
            System.out.println("Ad shown success");
        } else {
            Log.d(TAG, "Interstitial ad is not loaded yet");
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
        drawerListner.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onPostCreate(savedInstanceState);
        drawerListner.syncState();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

        MenuItem item = menu.add("share"); // your desired title here
        item.setIcon(R.drawable.share_icon); // your desired icon here
        item.setShowAsAction(MenuItem.SHOW_AS_ACTION_ALWAYS);

        item.setOnMenuItemClickListener(new OnMenuItemClickListener() {

            @Override
            public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem item) {
                try
                { Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);  
                  i.setType("text/plain");
                  i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "RGPV Digest");
                  String sAux = "Looking to score high in RGPV ?\n Try out this app :\n\n";
                  sAux = sAux + "https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=" + getApplicationContext().getPackageName();
                  i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, sAux);  
                  startActivity(Intent.createChooser(i, "Share via"));
                }
                catch(Exception e)
                { //e.toString();
                }   

                return true;
            }
        });

        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        if (drawerListner.onOptionsItemSelected(item)) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,
            long id) {

        if (position == 0) {

            Uri uri = Uri
                    .parse("https://2ce74af0d8de8783b91cdd315eeba0340a4b9277.googledrive.com/host/0B2sDUzNeIK0KODB0ZDRMVjFPaFE/Jobs.html");
            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uri);
            startActivity(intent);

        } else if (position == 1) {

            Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainCS.class);
            startActivityForResult(intent, 0);

        } else if (position == 2) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SENDTO, Uri.fromParts(
                    "mailto","laboratorypk@gmail.comm", null));
            intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "Project Help");
            intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT,"Please write a short description of your project and technology you are supposed to use.");
            startActivity(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Choose an Email client :"));
        }

        // }
        else if (position == 3) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(this, Careerguid.class);
            startActivityForResult(intent, 0);
        }

        else if (position == 4) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SENDTO, Uri.fromParts(
                    "mailto","laboratorypk@gmail.comm", null));
            intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "PC Games");
            intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT,"Hey! I need PC Games pls share the list of Games that you have.");
            startActivity(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Choose an Email client :"));
        }
        else if (position == 5) {
            Uri uri = Uri.parse("market://details?id=" + getApplicationContext().getPackageName());
            Intent goToMarket = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uri);
            try {
              startActivity(goToMarket);
            } catch (ActivityNotFoundException e) {
              startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("http://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=" + getApplicationContext().getPackageName())));
            }

        }

        else if (position == 6) {

            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SENDTO, Uri.fromParts(
                    "mailto","laboratorypk@gmail.comm", null));
            intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "Query/Feedback");
            intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT,"");
            startActivity(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Choose an Email client :"));
        }

        drawerLayout.closeDrawers();
        selectItem(position);
    }

    public void selectItem(int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        listView.setItemChecked(position, true);

    }

    public void setTitle(String title) {
        getSupportActionBar().setTitle(title);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        showInterstitial();
        super.onDestroy();
    }

    private Toast toast;
    private long lastBackPressTime = 0;

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        if (this.lastBackPressTime < System.currentTimeMillis() - 4000) {
            toast = Toast.makeText(this, "Press back again to exit",
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
            toast.show();

            this.lastBackPressTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
            drawerLayout.closeDrawers();
        } else {
            if (toast != null) {
                toast.cancel();
            }
            super.onBackPressed();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

}

class MyAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    private Context context;
    String[] navlist;
    int[] images = { R.drawable.job, R.drawable.facebook, R.drawable.project,
            R.drawable.career, R.drawable.games, R.drawable.rate, R.drawable.mail };

    public MyAdapter(Context context) {
        this.context = context;
        navlist = context.getResources().getStringArray(R.array.navdra);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return navlist.length;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return navlist[position];
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View row = null;
        if (convertView == null) {
            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
                    .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            row = inflater.inflate(R.layout.customrow, parent, false);
        }

        else {
            row = convertView;
        }
        TextView titleTextView = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.textView11);
        ImageView titleImageView = (ImageView) row
                .findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
        titleTextView.setText(navlist[position]);
        titleImageView.setImageResource(images[position]);

        return row;
    }

}
```

Here is activity_main.xml

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@drawable/ab" >

        <ScrollView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" >

            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical" >

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/imageView1"
                    android:layout_width="135dp"
                    android:layout_height="135dp"
                    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                    android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
                    android:src="@drawable/rgpvicon" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/rgpvtext"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/imageView1"
                    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                    android:layout_marginTop="6dp"
                    android:clickable="true"
                    android:text="RGPV Digest"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
                    android:textColor="@drawable/texteff"
                    android:textSize="36sp" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/compu"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/rgpvtext"
                    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                    android:layout_marginTop="25dp"
                    android:clickable="true"
                    android:text="Computer Science"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                    android:textColor="@drawable/texteff"
                    android:textSize="24sp" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/calc"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/compu"
                    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                    android:clickable="true"
                    android:text="Calculator"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                    android:textColor="@drawable/texteff"
                    android:textSize="24sp" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/iv"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/calc"
                    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                    android:clickable="true"
                    android:text="Interview Question"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                    android:textColor="@drawable/texteff"
                    android:textSize="24sp" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/prog"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/iv"
                    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                    android:clickable="true"
                    android:text="Programs"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                    android:textColor="@drawable/texteff"
                    android:textSize="24sp" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/abo"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/prog"
                    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                    android:clickable="true"
                    android:text="About"
                    android:paddingBottom="20dp"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                    android:textColor="@drawable/texteff"
                    android:textSize="24sp" />
            </RelativeLayout>
        </ScrollView>
    </LinearLayout>

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/drawerlist"
        android:layout_width="240dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="left"
        android:background="#4ABC96"
        android:paddingTop="6dp" />

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

LOG:

```
 Process: com.pKLabs.RgpvDigest, PID: 1557
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.pKLabs.RgpvDigest/com.pKLabs.RgpvDigest.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2184)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2233)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5001)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:785)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:601)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
     Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
            at com.pKLabs.RgpvDigest.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:146)
            at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5231)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2148)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2233)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5001)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:785)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:601)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
07-23 07:04:44.900      409-763/? W/ActivityManager﹕ Force finishing activity com.pKLabs.RgpvDigest/.MainActivity
07-23 07:04:45.080      409-428/? D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 312K, 54% free 5989K/12960K, paused 98ms, total 101ms
07-23 07:04:45.410    1557-1574/? D/dalvikvm﹕ DexOpt: --- BEGIN 'ads1355421311.jar' (bootstrap=0) ---
07-23 07:04:45.510      409-428/? I/Choreographer﹕ Skipped 38 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
```

Not able to figure out what am i doing wrong, i updated android studio and downloaded API 22 and after that i got many errors in My gradle too. I some how fixed that but it is run time error how can i fix please help me out.

Comment: paste your log. But I think that the problem is here `setContentView(activity_main);` it should be `setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);` or something like this

Comment: Already did that, still error is there

Comment: can you show line 146 in your code

Comment: show us line 146 from your code

Comment: 145-getSupportActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
146-getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

Comment: Removed that and able to activity started but my action bar icons got removed, how to fix...

Comment: try to remove this line `import static com.pKLabs.RgpvDigest.R.layout.activity_main;` and do again what I wrote above - > `setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)`

Answer (score 0):

Is your activity added in the manifest?

Comment: It is there:  
          
 <activity
            android:name="com.pKLabs.RgpvDigest.MainActivity"
            android:configChanges="orientation"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
          
        </activity>

Answer (score 0):

use `getSupportActionBar()` instead of `getActionBar()`.

Use

```
getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
```

Instead of

```
getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
```

and run the app again.

Comment: Still the error is there!
dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.2.1'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:6.5.87'
}
I think something is wrong with my dependencies

Comment: my suggestion would be to quickly solve this type of errors, you can use Eclipse for your project. and once all errors are resolved then import your project into Android Studio as it has facility to import Eclipse project.

Comment: I am using android studio :( and it is very buggy